# AnsyncTask to open web page

Tags: android

i am trying to use the Asynctask method to fetch data from a web server.

I have the following code.

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FetchData extends Activity {
private TextView textView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fetch_data);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
}

    private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
          String response = "";
          for (String url : urls) {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
              HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
              InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

              BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
              String s = "";
              while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                response += s;
              }

            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
          return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
          textView.setText(result);
        }
      }

      public void readWebpage(View view) {
        DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
        task.execute(new String[] {message});

}



}
```

My problem is this FetchData Activity in turn has to receive a data from MainActivity.
I have used intent to do so. Now, the intent I am using here, has the data from the MainActivity. This message contains the URL of the web server. I just need to use the message to obtain the results from web page.
I want to pass this message to the task.execute method so that it can return me the web page. How should I do it.?

Comment: Why not just pass the URL to the `DownloadWebPageTask` in the constructor?

Comment: actually, the URL has to be dynamically built based on what a user input. I have created the url in MainActivity. Next step, is to fetch results from this url using AsyncTask. for this I created a second class FetchData , and used intents to exchange the information.

Just now i put the entire getIntent method and the String message inside the public void readWebpage() class. I am getting no errors now, but will this work??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have all you need except `readWebpage` method call.

1. Change parameter of `readWebpage` to pass message:

   ```
   public void readWebpage(String message) {
     DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
     task.execute(new String[] {message});
   }
   ```
2. Add call of `readWebpage` as last line in `onCreate`:

   ```
   ...
   String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
   readWebpage( message );
   ```

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Although it removed the errors, i am not sure whether the AsyncTask is correctly defined. i have just reused the code from somewhere else. Could you please confirm whether its all right.?

Answer (score 0):

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        private int       webViewPreviousState;
        private final int PAGE_STARTED    = 0x1;
        private final int PAGE_REDIRECTED = 0x2;

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {
            webViewPreviousState = PAGE_REDIRECTED;
            mWebView.loadUrl(urlNewString);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            webViewPreviousState = PAGE_STARTED;
            if (dialog == null || !dialog.isShowing())
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(WebViewActivity.this, "", getString(R.string.loadingMessege), true, true,
                        new OnCancelListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                // do something
                            }
                        });
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            if (webViewPreviousState == PAGE_STARTED) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                dialog = null;
            }

        }
 });
```

Comment: Oh myy...a new code...i was following the code mentioned on android developers forum..:-(

Comment: ya...it worked...The only problem being now is that my server returns a JSON String. i need to parse it and present it in a listview...Any ideas.? Should I use the inbuilt jSON parser..?

Comment: yes, sure.. I have put up a different question on stackoverflow to show me a code snippet, but the guys there are hell bent in asking me to post my code. i am currently writing the code by following a tutorial. ANy other good tutorial will certainly  help me.:-) Here's my post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641903/parsing-json-string-obtained-frm-server-in-android#comment18715308_13641903

Comment: i am sending you the link hope which help you alot : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/