# Parsing JSON String obtained frm server in Android

Tags: android, json

I had gone through a link on parsing Json data on Android, but didnt understand pretty much.
I am getting the following JSON String from my server.

I  need to parse it and present it as a listview in my android app. ANy guidance or code snippet.?
Also since my Jason string has data for images, will the listview be able to display it properly?

My JSON String is:

```
{"results":{"result":[{"year":"2012","title":"The Amazing Spider-Man","details":"http:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/tt0948470","director":"Marc Webb","rating":"7.3","cover":"http:\/\/i.media-imdb.com\/images\/SF1f0a42ee1aa08d477a576fbbf7562eed\/realm\/feature.gif"},

{"year":"2014","title":"The Amazing Spider-Man 2","details":"http:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/tt0948470","director":"Marc Webb","rating":"7.3","cover":"http:\/\/ia.media-imdb.com\/images\/M\/MV5BMzk3MTE5MDU5NV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwMjY3NTY3._V1._SX54_CR0,0,54,74_.jpg"},

{"year":"2002","title":"Spider-Man","details":"http:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/tt0948470","director":"Sam Raimi","rating":"6.3","cover":"http:\/\/ia.media-imdb.com\/images\/M\/MV5BODUwMDc5Mzc5M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNDgzOTY0MQ@@._V1._SX54_CR0,0,54,74_.jpg"},

{"year":"2007","title":"Spider-Man 3","details":"http:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/tt1872181","director":"Sam Raimi","rating":"7.5","cover":"http:\/\/ia.media-imdb.com\/images\/M\/MV5BMjE1ODcyODYxMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjA1NDE3MQ@@._V1._SX54_CR0,0,54,74_.jpg"},

{"year":"2004","title":"Spider-Man 2","details":"http:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/tt1872181","director":"Sam Raimi","rating":"6.8","cover":"http:\/\/i.media-imdb.com\/images\/SFa26455c07afc3c94f52e95de50d5d814\/realm\/tv_series.gif"}]}}
```

Comment: have you even tried anything ? google knows tons of example for what you are asking...

Comment: ya..i am putting up my tried code in a minute

Comment: @PSN your json code is valid now edit your native code.

Comment: @chintankhetiya  yes. I know my Json is valid . i had tried it on a json validator. I am now writing my code to parse it. will put it up in sometime if I dont understand a point.

Comment: @PSN you should write your code before posting here!

Comment: @M Mohsin Naeem I am writing my code. the only thing i was getting confused is whether i should use another activity for it or write in in my current activity. Basic Json parsing should work here I guess. i am trying it now as you write. Will update my code here soon.

Comment: @PSN If my answer is helping you then please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make Arraylist of All Fields and Write below function to parse above json, it will solve your problem.

```
ArrayList<String> year, title, details, director, rating, cover;
// For Parse Login Response From Server
public void mParseResponse() throws UnknownHostException { 

    year=new ArrayList<String>();
    title=new ArrayList<String>();
    details=new ArrayList<String>();
    director=new ArrayList<String>();
    rating=new ArrayList<String>();
    cover=new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
        JSONObject jsonobjresults = jObject.getJSONObject("results");
        JSONArray jsonarrayresult = jsonobjresults.getJSONArray("result");
        for(int i=0;i<jsonarrayresult.length(); i++){
            JSONObject mJsonObj = jsonarrayresult.getJSONObject(i);
            year.add(mJsonObj.getString("year"));
            title.add(mJsonObj.getString("title"));
            details.add(mJsonObj.getString("details"));
            director.add(mJsonObj.getString("director"));
            rating.add(mJsonObj.getString("rating"));
            cover.add(mJsonObj.getString("cover"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i make an arraylist of all fields..? i am new to java programming. Could you provide me with a code snippet for understanding.? Also I am using AsyncTask to retrieve my json String.

Comment: It shows 3 errors: respObject cannot be resolved., Entity cannot be resolved  and jsonresults cannot be resolved.

Comment: it says now entity cannot be resolved...But i need to display the parsed result as a list view. How do I do that.?

Comment: @PSN Pass your json string value instead of EntityUtils.toString(entity).

Comment: I am updating my code. The error now reads: unreachable code. Please check my updated code

Comment: i am posting it as another thread. i will post the link soon. heres my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643863/how-to-create-a-listview-with-custom-adapter

Comment: @PSN I check your code, your code is now complete, use response instead of EntityUtils.toString(entity)

Comment: Did you check my code on that link. ? It says error where i have called the mParseResponse(response). It says code unreachable

Comment: @PSN Write return response; after mParseResponse(response); it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

read this tutorial http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html.

You can use gson library of Google to parse json.
you need to create java classes to store json values
passs that class ref to gson libary. It has simple methods.

chec this [doc](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html)